# How to check list of environment variable in python?

Tags: python

I have requirement to check list of environment variable in Linux. Based on environment variable, exit code will be different. how to optimize the below code?

```
def check_mandatory_envs():
    if "ENVCONTEST_1" not in os.environ:
        exit(125)
    if "ENVCONTEST_2" not in os.environ:
        exit(126)
    if "ENVVIRTEST_3" not in os.environ
        exit(127)
    if "ENVVIRTEST_4" not in os.environ
        exit(128)
    if "ENVPATHTEST_5" not in os.environ
        exit(129)
    if "ENVPATHTEST_6" not in os.environ
        exit(130)
```

Comment: Where does `exit(...)` come from? Are you using something like `from sys import exit` at the beginning of your script?

Comment: @AlexV `exit` is a builtin as far as I know.

Comment: @JAD It is, but there are [noticeable differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6501134/5682996) between calling `exit`, `sys.exit`, and `os.exit`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group the messages and corresponding exit codes into a dict, and then iterate over that one:

```
def check_mandatory_envs():
    exit_codes = {
        "ENVCONTEST_1" :125,
        "ENVCONTEST_2" :126,
        "ENVVIRTEST_3" :127,
        "ENVVIRTEST_4" :128,
        "ENVPATHTEST_5":129,
        "ENVPATHTEST_6":130,
    }
    for variable, code in exit_codes.items():
        if variable not in os.environ:
            exit(code)
```

If the order of the iteration is important and you are on python before 3.6, you canuse a `collections.OrderedDict` or a list of tuples, without the `.items()` call

Comment: Is there an advantage of using a dictionary here compared to, say, a tuple of tuples or something similar?

Comment: Not really, there is no real downside either as far as I know. This also conveys that a certain variable has one exit code, and it throws a `SyntaxError` at compile time if you forgot an exit code or a comma, making input errors easier to find.